# How to solve this plotting problem in serial communication?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, matplotlib, serial-port

Here this simple code:

```
#import serial
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import serial

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.show()
fig.canvas.draw()



ser = serial.Serial('COM35', 115200, timeout=.1)
while True:
  data = ser.readline()
  print(data)
  plt.plot(data)
  fig.canvas.draw()
```

now when i run this i'm getting something like this..in pic[image]
and the data values are like this[image]

but i need output something like this (which is continuous graph)..[image]

but after adding the **list** key word on to the `list(ser.readline())` I get this error..[image]

Comment: @PatrickArtner the problem comes when i try to plot the data.. if you look the graph it's not continuous... for each time it try's to plot the data in same graph (but i need continuous plot..(live plot, with animation)).. did you understand what i say ?

Comment: @PatrickArtner check the above for expected output..Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the edit - It looks much clearer now :)

Comment: @PatrickArtner no , the data is continuously monitoring(it's live data there are no delay)

Comment: You plot a single line per serial read cycle. Your `plot` has no `y` values, hence the numbers 0,1,2 etc are used. You will find a solution when googling for matplotlib serial animation or similar.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest yes google and tried many other code but it's seems nothing works..it's been two day's i stuck with this problem..

Comment: Please link to the code you have been trying to adapt for your needs.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest i have given already the code it's above..or you mean MCU code?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest i'm getting this error `ValueError: could not convert string to float: b"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00(Lj\x80\x86\x88\x86sW;\x15\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1b@fw\x82\x8b\x8a}hJ)\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04-Tg\x7\n"`

Comment: If the question is about the error you get, [edit] it accordingly and I will reopen.

Comment: @PatrickArtner really thanks for your time.. yes i know, i'm working with this problem for 2 days..

Comment: Yes, I reopenend. But I have honestly no clue what the actual problem is. On the one hand there is a figure produced on the other hand there is an error. @PatrickArtner Maybe consider giving your answer at the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20572815/how-to-update-values-from-serial-port-in-matplotlib-animations?noredirect=1&lq=1) if you feel that it's better than the existing one.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thanks for reopening the question.. but when i run that program that you have linked i get error like `ValueError: could not convert string to float` but after adding the **list()** keyword the program is stops for some time and than i get this error `ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape` which i have linked above.(last pic)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest the animation would be a better way to solve the meta-problem - my code does not use animation but redraws on it's own. I see if I can convert it to using animation - the other Q especially askes for usage of animation package hence the existing answer is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is not as elegant as using the [animation-api](https://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html) - but it works.

You have to adapt quite a lot - for sake of giving a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I had to implement my own "serial" dataprovider:

```
from itertools import cycle 
data = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,25,64,92,119,132,139,124,123,103,71,38,3]
cyc = cycle(data)

def serial():
    from random import randint
    def create_data():
        for k in range(randint(2,3)): 
            yield next(cyc) 
    return list(create_data())
```

One way to solve it:

You need to get the the axes of your plot as well to adjust the "area" that is shown, then you need to supply correct x-values as "time" and the y-values as reading from serial (you can increment a "how many data received" variable on each draw for the *time*):

```
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 


fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
ax.set_ylim(-200, 200)
ax.set_xlim(0,110)
fig.show()
fig.canvas.draw() 

time = 0
last = 0
while True:
    # "animate" x-axis
    if time > 100:
        ax.set_xlim(time-100,time+10)
    data = serial()
    print(data)
    # add the last datapoint again so you get a continuous curve
    plt.plot([time-1]+[time+x for x in range(len(data))], [last]+data)
    # increment time
    time += len(data)
    # remember last data-value
    last = data[-1]
    fig.canvas.draw()
```

To get (text output omitted - it just repeats the data from above differently chunked):

[image: animation]

You can see by the colored line-segments which data was added together.

Comment: do you have any idea why the graph is not proper DC-signal ? is there way to fix that?

Comment: @user3764118 I have no clue what you mean with "proper DC-Signal" ... it displays the data it gets. I choose to use the few datapoints provided by your question and _loop_ them around so it is the same wave-form given ...just with different chunking on the data. You can play around with the axis-limits and/or widen/shorten the x-increment to make it flatter/sharper. If you want "rectangular" waves, you need data that supports this.

Answer (score 0):

You could also change to use the [animation](https://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html) module of matplotlib - this answer is heavily inspired by [tacaswell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/380231/tacaswell) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20575424/7505395) to [How to update values from serial port in matplotlib animations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20572815/how-to-update-values-from-serial-port-in-matplotlib-animations?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Same data generator:

```
from itertools import cycle 
data = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,25,64,92,119,132,139,124,123,103,71,38,3]
cyc = cycle(data)

def serial():
    from random import randint
    def create_data():
        for k in range(randint(2,3)): 
            yield next(cyc) 
    return list(create_data())
```

---

> ```
> from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
> from matplotlib import animation
> import numpy as np
>
> fig = plt.figure()
> ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 150), ylim=(-200, 200))
> ```

```
max_points = 150
```

> ```
> # fill initial artist with nans (so nothing draws)
> line, = ax.plot(np.arange(max_points), 
>                 np.ones(max_points, dtype=np.float)*np.nan, 
>                 lw=2)
> def init():
>     return line,
>
> def animate(i):
> ```

```
    y = serial() # arduino.readline()
    old_y = line.get_ydata()               # adjusted here for this question data, coming
    new_y = np.r_[old_y[len(y):], y]       # in as chunks rather then single values
```

> ```
>     line.set_ydata(new_y)
>     return line,
>
>
> anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=200, interval=20, blit=False) 
> plt.show()
> ```

---

The adaptations made to @tacaswell's code are due to the fact that this questions data needed other limits for the output graph and that the data coming in for *this question* provides multiple, chunked datapoints, not single values. The "data-refresh" in `def animate(i)` had to be adapted to work for this.

Comment: @tacaswell I heavily leaned on your answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20572815/how-to-update-values-from-serial-port-in-matplotlib-animations?noredirect=1&lq=1 - if you feel it is too much (or not enough attributation) feel free to tell me and I'll fix it (or delete it)

Comment: the second solution looks good but why i get some tump on the graph  and when i print the value of `data`(serial data) i get lot's of `'nan'` value why ? do you have any idea ?

Comment: @user3764118  NaN are not drawn - the datagraph is initialized to NaN it - and then filled incrementally by the animate() function - this code does not USE your actual data - the code here gets `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,25,64,92,119,132,139,124,123,103,71,38,3]` all the time - which are the values you gave in your question - it simply displays the data given - if your source data does not lead to the results you want you probably have to change something for gathering the data (or preprocessing it).